# Flutter ColorScheme being ignored

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to set up a very basic black and white colour scheme, but when I go to use it, it seems like it's picking up the default blue theme.

What am I doing wrong? Is it to do with the context?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyAppextends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'MyApp',
        theme: ThemeData(
          appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark),
          colorScheme: ColorScheme(
            brightness: Brightness.light,
            primary: Colors.black,
            onPrimary: Colors.white,
            secondary: Colors.white,
            onSecondary: Colors.black,
            error: Colors.red,
            onError: Colors.white,
            background: Colors.grey.shade100,
            onBackground: Colors.black,
            surface: Colors.grey.shade200,
            onSurface: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          body: const Center(
            child: Text("Welcome"),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary, // <== coming in as blue instead of black
            child: Row(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: because you're trying to get the primary color on the ``context`` which doesn't hold the updated color scheme values. If you create another statefull/stateless widget and then get the color, it'll work as the context is updated. Check demo https://dartpad.dev/?id=2501f2d64531a47e3fb2c13954fdaad8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting theme and trying to get on the same context with `Theme.of(context)`. You can separate the context(creating new widget) or just use `Builder` widget for `home`

```dart
home: Builder(builder: (context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: const Center(
      child: Text("Welcome"),
    ),
```